# UIPageViewController transitionCoordinator

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, transition-coordinator

Is it possible to get hold of the `transitionCoordinator` of a `UIPageViewController`?

Every time I try to get it it's `nil`. Does it even use one?

If not, is there a non-hacky way of responding to the progress of a scroll between pages?

(hacky = iterating subviews to get scroll view and becoming scroll view delegate. This isn't ideal because of the "magic" that `UIPageViewController` does with its scroll view)

Thanks

Comment: What do you intend to do with the progress? Maybe there's another way of obtaining that information/performing the action.

Comment: @Alistra I have a background that needs to change colour between pages. e.g. on page 1 it will be red and on page 2 it will be orange. Need to animate between red and orange alongside the scroll between pages. I've done it as an example in a scroll view but struggling to find an easy way to do it in a UIPageViewController.

Comment: Hey @Fogmeister, ever find a workaround?

Comment: Any chance you found progress?

Comment: UIPageViewController has another problem that it unexpectedly adds other page's views to the window after the current page does viewDidAppear https://stackoverflow.com/q/43531127/259521

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After years of experimentation, I have *never* found a situation in which the `transitionCoordinator` of a UIPageViewController is not `nil`.

And, as Fogmeister points out in this original question and comments, there is also therefore no good way to track the page view controller scroll animation and coordinate with it.

My solution is to roll my own paging scroll view that does what UIPageViewController does, i.e. it preloads the page views before and after this one, but no others, so that memory is conserved. Now we have an ordinary scroll view, we can serve as its delegate, and we can do anything we like in connection with the scroll.

It isn't all that difficult, and is in fact what we used to do before there was a UIPageViewController (yes, I remember those days well).

Apple even provides an example of how to do it: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty much how I’ve done it in when responding to the scrollview is required.

Comment: Should we file enhancement requests with Apple?

Comment: Possibly worth it. If enough people request it might get some traction.